# Multiple objects, one animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move multiple characters using a single animation. I tried to use loop for this but failed. Can you help? I want to return the characters I added under GameObject.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 
public class ses : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource audioSource;
    public Animator animator;
    public GameObject[] karakul;
    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        //animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
    }
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "sayiCollider")
        {
 
            audioSource.Play();
            foreach (var item in karakul)
            {
                animator.SetBool("clap", true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("clap", false);
        }
   
    }
 
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzSAF.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPrbT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myCVb.png)

Comment: You can use one **AnimationClip** and one **AnimatorController**, but you have to create an Animator for each GameObject.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through the GameObjects, and every time set a param on an animator, which is nothing to do with those GameObjects.

Usually, the crowd has solved another way for performance, but to answer your question, you need to add an Animator component to all GameObject you want to animate and call the SetBool on them, something like that:

```
[SerializeField] private Animator[] _animators;

private void OnTiggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    bool isSayi = other.CompareTag("sayiCollider");

    if (isSayi) audioSource.Play();
    else audioSource.Stop();

    for (int i = 0; i < _animators.Length; i++) _animators[i].SetBool("clap", isSayi);
}
```

Comment: This code makes a lot of sense but it failed to detect the collision. Music did not play, animation did not play.

Comment: Hmmm.

The `OnTriggerEnter()` must be in a class inherited from `MonoBehaviour`, and a collider on the GameObject. Also one of the GameObjects has to have a Rigidbody for collision.

Are all the animations' references added to the array in the inspector, as well as the AudioSource?